# Bold and italic displaying incorrectly in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, text-formatting, rendering

(I'm not a native English speaker, sorry if my English is not perfect).

I'm using MS Word, 16.52, on a MacBook Pro, macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Today I noticed a problem in the displaying of some typefaces in Word.

While bold and italic used independently seem to work mostly fine, in many typefaces (Libertinus Serif, Alegreya, Noto Sans...) if I format a text in bold *and* italic together it does not show as bold & italic, but instead as bold & faux-italic, "slanted" bold.
The problem seems to exist only for the specific "bold" weight. In typefaces with more weights, if in the menu I select e.g. "semibold italic" or "light italic", it displays correctly (i.e. semibold & real-italic or light & real-italic, not slanted).
Also, in the font menu or in the "character" window the bold-italic option appears correctly formatted, in bold & real-italic, but it anyway appears as bold & faux-italic when on the page.

The problem does not show with all typefaces; some of them seem to work fine (Times New Roman).

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling a typeface with this problem (Fira Sans), but nothing changed.

Also, I noticed that in some typefaces (Bembo, Minion 3) now "bold" shows as bold & italic (!). Again, this seems to happen only for the "bold" weight; I can have "semibold" without italic, but it seems I can't have "bold" without italic...

I don't know exactly when this problem began, but some time ago everything was working fine, at least with the typefaces I used then (I checked a PDF I formatted in Baskerville on June 15th — the bold-italic was displaying correctly, now it is not).

It's very annoying and I have no idea how to solve it.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Do you actually have the required font style in the family? If not, Word will quite happily make up one on the fly - which usually looks abysmal. Of those three fonts, I only have Alegreya Sans SC… & I don't see any bold italic https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4mTZ.png This is a font from an ancient foundry catalogue I've had for years [perhaps decades], so I can't claim it will be full & up to date. [btw, why on earth are you trying to do serious typesetting in Word??!?? ;) Ah…  I also have Minion… the *full* set - https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5Q3x.png

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, I have all of them. This is the Alegreya Sans I have, with bold-italic and other weights: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alegreya+Sans . As I wrote, in the menus the font styles show correctly, with bold-italic (so I definitely have the right styles installed), but do not show when applied on the page. The other weights work fine (semibold-italic, light-italic, etc.), but bold-italic does not.

Comment: I'd test in Pages & in TextEdit to see if it's a Microsoft 'thing'… it usually is. Do you *have* to do this in Word?

Comment: @Tetsujin In TextEdit, Photoshop, Mail, everything seems to work fine. In Excel some styles need to be selected from the menu and not thought shortcuts, but then they work fine (also the ones not working in Word). In PowerPoint I have the same problems I have in Word (some "bolds" show as bold-italic, while some "bold-italic" show as slanted bolds...), *but* not always with the same typefaces. Nobody forces me to use Word, but as all of my work is written and formatted in Word, what I need is to solve the problem, clearly... :P

Comment: Sorry, I'm outside my area of expertise. The only time I ever use Word is if someone sends me something that Preview can't handle ;)